# After insert on object A must update a field on Object B

Tags: apex

I have a standard object - Livechattranscript and a custom object - getfeedback__c. When a record is inserted in livechattranscript, I want to update a field called live_chat_transcript__c in getfeedback__c object with the id of the livechattranscript record that was just inserted.

I have written the below code and its just not working the way it should

```
trigger updateRecordOnGF on LiveChattranscript (after insert) {
    Map<Id, Getfeedback__c> gfs = new Map<Id, Getfeedback__c>();
    for (LiveChattranscript lcts : Trigger.new) {
        if (lcts.chatbrand__c=='Ziphosting') {
            gfs.put(
                    lcts.id,
                    new getfeedback__c(live_chat_transcript__c = lcts.Id)
                    );
        }
    }
    update getfeedback__c.values();
}
```

Please help...

I want to include another condition in the if statement, which is - when the chatkey field of livechattranscript = chatkey__c field of getfeedback__C I want to populate the field live_chat_transcript__c of getfeedback with id of livechattranscript

Answer (score 1):

change the trigger name on the current trigger..

Comment: Hi Bhaskar, No matter what nsme I change it to, I get the same error.

Answer (score 0):

The error message clearly indicates that you have a trigger in your environment by the same name on the **"GetFeedback__c"** object.

So modify the name of your trigger and provide a unique name.

Regards!
Ruchi

Comment: Hi Ruchi, no matter what name I change it to, I get the same error